# How to use <col> tag correctly and is it supported in all browser?

Tags: css, cross-browser, xhtml, html-table

What is the use of `<col>` tag and is it supported in all browser?

I was trying `<col style="background:red">` but it's not working. I'm on Firefox 3.

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <col style="background:red">
  <caption> Table Caption </caption>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works, but it doesn't affect the caption. Working example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <caption>test</caption>
  <col style="background:red" />
  <col style="background:blue" />
  <tr>
    <td>red</td>
    <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>red</td>
    <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The tag is defined in HTML 4.01 (1997) and not deprecated in XHTML, so it should be supported (as far as the user interface allows) by every current browser on any platform.

Comment: +1 Thanks Guffa and what is the difference between `col` and `colgroup`? and like from `<col>` we can select any column of table ? is there a way to select row of table?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: The `colgroup` element can be used for a group of `col` elements, where you can specify attributes that apply to all columns in the group, and then override some attribute on some columns. To specify attributes for rows, you simply apply them to the `tr` elements, and the only grouping available is the `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` elements.

Comment: thanks for reply - so like with col we can select any column , there is no option in HTML to select any row. what if i want to select some specific rows inside `<tbody>`

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: You can put a class in the `tr` elements and define the style for them in a style sheet. Otherwise you have to add the same attributes to each `tr` element.

Comment: The xhtml example above is slightly incorrect.  The <caption> must come before any <col> or <colgroup> elements.

Comment: @pgoetz: Thanks for spotting that, I corrected the code. Note that the standard doesn't specify the position of the `caption` element in relation to `col` or `colgroup` elements, but rather that it has to be the first element in the table.

Comment: I've been spending a lot of time staring at the xhtml strict/transitional DTD's.  If you look at the DTD, the required ordering is clear.  How this is implemented in browsers is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 2):

It is used in tables to set default attributes for all the cells in a column or a group of columns.

The col tag is defined in an ordered way and can be part of a HTML colgroup tag or not.

It is supported in all browsers.